# Fourier transform and tempered distribution

Tags: fourier-transform, linear-pde

I see a statement that: for every tempered function $f$ and a "polynomial" of derivative operator $P(D)$ with constant coefficient, we can prove that the constant coefficient PDE

$P(D)u=f$,

has a tempered solution $u$ by using the following result:

For every tempered distribution $F$ and non zero polynomial $P$, we can find a tempered distribution $S$ such that:

$F=PS$,

And applying fourier transform on both sides of the equation.

I've seen it in corollary 1 and corollary 3 of Atiyah's paper:
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/cpa.3160230202

Or a more straight forward reference, in the page 1 of this paper by Hormander: [https://math.uchicago.edu/~shmuel/lg-readings/Hormander,%20division.pdf](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eshmuel/lg-readings/Hormander,%20division.pdf)

Maybe it's a trivial question but I'm confused because fourier transform would only carry distribution to distribution, I wonder how the do we obtain the function $P(D)u, f$ by applying fourier transform to distribution $PS, F$?

Thanks you for your answer!

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you have written. If $S$ is tempered, then won't also $PS=F$ be tempered? Have you swapped the roles of $F$ and $S$?

Comment: You should clarify the relationship between $u$ and $S$ and between $f$ and $F$.

Comment: @md2perpe Sorry for this, here $F$ is also tempered.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I'm also curious about the explicit relationship of $F, P, S$ and $f, P(D), u$, I don't know how to use fourier transform to connect this pair of datas.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I've edited this question to make it more clear, please read again, thank!

Comment: Could you provide a link to where you have seen this? It's still a bit unclear, but I suppose that it's related to the Fourier transform of $P(\frac{d}{dx})u(x) = f(x)$ being $P(i\xi) \hat{u}(\xi) = \hat{f}(\xi).$

Comment: @md2perpe I see it in corollary 1 of Atiyah's paper: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/cpa.3160230202

Comment: @md2perpe There is also a same statement in reference 3 of Atiyah's paper.